# Jquery add diez tag for hashtag does not work on firefox, safari and mobile phones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, firefox, safari

I am having a problem with Firefox and Safari. I have tried to make a hashtag system for automatically add `#(diez)` tag. My code is working fine on chrome but it is not working on Firefox and Safari.

When you open this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EmaejY)** with chrome and write something with space you can see my js code is working fine. But when you open **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EmaejY)** with Mozilla Firefox it is not working with space. Firefox deletes space not adding `#(diez)` tag.

Safari and all mobile browser problem is does not work any code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Move cursor to the end.
function placeCaretAtEndX(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

// Define special characters:
var characters = new Set([
  0, 32, // space
  13, // enter
  // add other punctuation symbols or keys
]);

// Add hashtags on each word.
function addHashtags(text) {
  // Add hashtag.
  text = text.replace(/([\w]+)/gi, function addHashtag(x){ return '#' + x; });
   
  // Remove duplicated words
    text = text.replace(/\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)/gi, function removeDuplicates(x) { return ''; });

    // Prevent single/double hashtags
    text = text.replace(/[#]{2,}/gi, function removeDoubleHashtags(x) { return '#'; });
    text = text.replace(/[#]{1}\s+/gi, function removeSingleHashtags(x) { return ''; });

  // Prevent double spaces  
  text = text.replace(/  /g, ' ');
   
  text = text.trim();
  // return results
  return text;
}

// Convert characters to charCode
function toCharCodeX(char) { return char.charCodeAt(0); }




var forbiddenCharactersX = new Set([
  toCharCodeX("_"),
  toCharCodeX("-"),
  toCharCodeX("?"),
  toCharCodeX("*"),
  toCharCodeX("\\"),
  toCharCodeX("/"),
  toCharCodeX("("),
  toCharCodeX(")"),
  toCharCodeX("="),
  toCharCodeX("&"),
  toCharCodeX("%"),
  toCharCodeX("+"),
  toCharCodeX("^"),
  toCharCodeX("#"),
  toCharCodeX("'"),
  toCharCodeX("<"),
  toCharCodeX("|"),
  toCharCodeX(">"),
  toCharCodeX("."),
  toCharCodeX(","),
  toCharCodeX(";")
]);

  

  $("body").on("keypress","#text", function (e) {
    if (characters.has(e.keyCode)) {
      // Get and modify text.
      var text = $("#text").text();
      text = addHashtags(text);
      // Save content.
      $("#text").text(text);
      // Move cursor to the end
      placeCaretAtEndX(document.querySelector("#text"));
    } else if (forbiddenCharactersX.has(e.keyCode)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:10px;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:50px;
}
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.addiez {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
   outline:none;
   text-transform: lowercase;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.addiez::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   color: rgb(0, 0, 1);
}
.addiez[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before  {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      color: #444;
    }

.note {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
.ad_text {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:10px 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="addiez" contenteditable="true" id="text" placeholder="Write something with space"></div>
   <div class="ad_text" id="ad_text"></div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar no dear i am not getting any error from the Javascript console.

Comment: It works in Safari for me, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your check. What is the problem `forbiddenCharactersX` codes also that is not working on FF.

Comment: @Barmar In firefox working like this `.#dfsa,#fdsa-#fdasf*#fads` . I mean #(diez) adding after `forbiddenCharactersX` characters.

Comment: It looks like `new Set(<array>)` isn't working, it's creating empty sets.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. It's just the stack snippet fake console that can't display sets.

Comment: In Firefox `e.keyCode` is always `0`. See the linked question for the correct way to get the key.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much. I learned a new code.

Comment: @Barmar i have just one question. The codes working on your mobile phone?

Comment: haven't tried it on mobile, just on OS X

Comment: @Barmar can you try it for me please?

Comment: I don't have Safari or FF on mobile device, just Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar No problem just, can you try Chrome for a mobile device. Is it works for you?

Comment: I don't get any hashtags in mobile Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar yes there is a big problem for me. :(

Comment: I don't have remote debugging in my mobile Chrome, so I can't investigate.

Comment: @Barmar Codes are not working just on Chrome, it didn't work all mobile browsers. :( I don't know if i ask my question again some people angry to me about same question. You closed my question.

Comment: Touch devices might not have the `keypress` event. Try using `keydown` or `keyup`, or `input`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes i am already tryed keydown and keyup but not tryed input. keyup and keydown didn't worked.

Comment: @Barmar If i use input like this [example](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/RZwrzQ) i can not press space for other hashtags.

Comment: Try using jquery-mobile, I think it will synthesize events on desktop devices.

Comment: @Barmar I have tryed [HERE](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EmaejY) nothing changed. I also added alert(); then alert also not working. :S

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about this. Write a new question that's just about getting the keypress event on a mobile device. Remove everything else from the example, the hashtag stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean with this word Dear `(Remove everything else from the example, the hashtag stuff is irrelevant.)`

Comment: the problem you're having is that the event handler isn't running when the user types. So it doesn't matter what it does, just make a simple example that just does `console.log(something)`.

Comment: @Barmar I asked [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270828/keypress-event-on-a-mobile-device)